# C struct is nil when return in Go

Tags: pointers, go, struct, cgo

I am trying to create a C struct point and pass it to Go but I keep getting a nil pointer. I have the following in C and calling from Go.

test.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct TestStruct {
    int test_int;
} TestStruct;

TestStruct* newTestStruct();
```

test.c

```
TestStruct* newTestStruct() {
    printf("[C] Creating TestStruct...\n");
    TestStruct test = {0};

    test.test_int = 10;

    TestStruct* testPtr = &test;

    if (testPtr == NULL) {
        printf("[C] TestStruct is NULL.\n");
    }

    fflush(stdout);
    return testPtr;
}
```

test.go

```
package teststruct

import "log"

// #include "test.h"
import "C"

type TestStruct C.struct_TestStruct

func NewTestStruct() *TestStruct {
    t := C.newTestStruct()

    if t == nil {
        log.Errorf("[Go] TestStruct is nil.")
    }

    return (*TestStruct)(t)
}
```

It prints off the following:

```
[C] Creating TestStruct...
[Go] TestStruct is nil.
```

Why is this nil on the Go side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a stack-allocated structure in C, which is *very wrong*.

The pointer returned from `newTestStruct` is essentially *dangling* and trying to access any data through it may lead to crashes or worse.

Make sure to allocate data on the heap if you want to return a pointer to it, something like:

```
TestStruct* newTestStruct() {
    printf("[C] Creating TestStruct...\n");
    TestStruct* testPtr = (TestStruct*)malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));
    testPtr->test_int = 10;

    if (testPtr == NULL) {
        printf("[C] TestStruct is NULL.\n");
    }

    fflush(stdout);
    return testPtr;
}
```

---

By the way, on any half-modern C compiler you'd get a warning for your C code, something like `warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]`